# How to store and manage large files

Tags: java, database, file, frameworks

Did anybody know a java framework to store and handle large number of files? I am searching for an alternative to store my files into a SQL BLOB field.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) claims to support large number of large files..

Answer (score 1):

If you need meta data for the files as well, you might want to look at something like [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/).